# Is there a REST API for Cloudera health checks?

Tags: rest, cloudera, impala, health-monitoring

I'm looking for a REST call to perform a health check on my Impala daemons thru an F5 VIP.  I was looking at the docs for Cloudera and I didn't quite find what I'm looking for, although [this link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cm_ht_impala_daemon.html#concept_s35_xbn_yk) is close to what I'm looking for.  It refers to an Impala daemon host health check returning true or false.  However, it doesn't tell me if it's a REST call or API call to access this check.

Does anyone know how I can access this check thru an F5?  If this isn't the health check I'm looking for, can someone tell me where to find it?

Comment: I'm not sure what an F5 VIP is or if its a critical factor in this question. You should be able to user the time series api in a rest call to the Cloudera Manager -> https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v15/path__timeseries.html

There is also a metrics endpoint, but thats deprecated

Comment: @owen79, thx for your tip.  The VIP is a virtual IP.  It's the IP for my load balancer.  I need the load balancer to perform a health check on each of our impala daemons so it knows whether to route traffic to the daemon or not.  This is why I need some REST call to each daemon to determine if it's up or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from Cloudera answered my question at [this link](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Is-there-a-REST-health-check-for-the-impala-daemons/m-p/58346#M3362).

Quoting what they said:

```
Cloudera Manager internally queries this page provided by Impala daemon host:

http://<impala-daemon-url>:25000/inflight_query_ids

to determine if the impala is responding to requests
```